# texlod() is not supported on ps_4_0_level_9_3 , how can I do a similar operation in this case?

Tags: opengl, directx, hlsl, directx9

Ihave an interesting problem for you guys

I am trying to compile a pixel shader that I ported from GLSL and I am having trouble with a texCUBElod() function that the compiler say's is not supported on the current target, which is ps_4_0_level_9_3  in this case.

Here is the function I am trying to  compile:

```
uniform samplerCUBE EnvMap;
uniform float EnvMapLod;
float4 FS():COLOR:
{ 
   float4 color;
  float4 reflected;

   /*
   Processing values
   */

  color = texCUBElod(EnvMap, float4(reflected, EnvMapLod));
  return color
}
```

The compiler returns this error:

```
error X4532: texlod not supported on this target
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's not available on the ps_4_0_level_9_3 target.

If we look at [the documentation for texCUBElod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509690(v=vs.85).aspx) we see that it's only available in the pixel shader and only for Shader Model 3 and 4 targets; it's not available at all for Shader Model 1 and 2 targets.

Cross-check with [the documentation for ps_4_0_level_9_3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj215820(v=vs.85).aspx#direct3d_9.1__9.2__and_9.3_feature_levels) and we find that this is actually a Shader Model 2 target (with a handful of additional capabilities), not a full Shader Model 3 target.

texCUBElod is not one of those additional capabilities, hence it's not available.

Footnote 2 explains this (my emphasis):

> Feature level 9.3 effectively requires hardware that complies with the requirements for legacy Direct3D 9 shader model 3.0, but **this feature level does not make use of vs_3_0 or ps_3_0 targets**.

The solution is to use [the legacy Direct3D 9 Shader Model 3.0 target](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj215820(v=vs.85).aspx#Legacy_D3D9_Shader_Model_3), i.e. **ps_3_0**, not ps_4_0_level_9_3.

Comment: OK, well since I am forced to use the 9.3 target I guess I'll have to work around that somehow. 
Thank you very much

Comment: In Direct3D 11 there's basically no option for using Shader Model 3.0. There are a number of technical and historical reasons for this--see [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels/)--, but remember that 9.3 uses ``vs_2_0`` and ``ps_2_x``.

Comment: @DemetrioProgramerOsorio - I assumed from your question tags that you were using D3D9 but with the D3DCompile API.  Could you confirm which version please?  If you really do need to sample a specific mipmap level you can use sampler states to select it instead.

Comment: 9.3 is my target